# Running Dropbear SSH server completely from SD card because filesystem is read only

Tags: arm

I want to exploit a specific binary on a embedded device [First Part of Examining IP Camera](https://herrfeder.github.io/embeddedsec/2017/10/19/Hacking-A-IP-Camera-Part1.html). As this binary won't execute outside the embedded device I'm heading to examine it remotely.
It has an SD card slot for storing pictures and videos. I cross compiled dropbear statically for this platform and executed it with success.

For allowing my host to ssh into the target device I have to add the id_rsa key into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the device. As root is mounted completely read only

```
/mnt/disc1/dropbear_armv5 # touch ~/.ssh
touch: /root/.ssh: Read-only file system
```

I would like to find a way to specify the location of the keys elsewhere or execute it without using any keys. Knows someone a way of achieving this? In case I misunderstood principles of doing this help would be appreciated too.

On the target

```
/mnt/disc1/dropbear_armv5 # ./dropbear_static -r dropbear_dss_host_key -r   dropbear_rsa_host_key -B -E
/mnt/disc1/dropbear_armv5 # [27893] Jan 31 22:09:57 Running in background
[28019] Jan 31 22:10:28 Child connection from 192.168.12.1:47398
[28019] Jan 31 22:10:29 Login attempt for nonexistent user from 192.168.12.1:47398
[28019] Jan 31 22:10:29 Login attempt for nonexistent user from 192.168.12.1:47398
[28019] Jan 31 22:10:32 Exit before auth: Exited normally
```

On the host

```
# ssh -i ip_cam_rsa root@192.168.12.176                         :(
root@192.168.12.176's password: 

Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: I think dropbear has options to specifiy the directory of the keys. Another technique is to mod the firmware (adding dropbear plus keys), and repackage it. You will need to check if the vendor uses a checksum in their firmware headers, but the tool Binwalk is very helpful.

Comment: @GusGorman402 OpenSSH has these options, but Dropbear doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbear hard-codes the location `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in its source code, where `~` is the home directory of the target user as read from the user database. If you can't change the user database and can't make the home directory read-write, then you need to modify the source code.

You may be able to make the home directory read-write by mounting a different filesystem over it. That depends what tools are available on the device. For example, maybe you can arrange to mount an in-memory filesystem:

```
mount -t tmpfs root /root
cp -Rp /somewhere/writable/root/.ssh /root/
dropbear
```

Or maybe you can make a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount):

```
mount --bind /somewhere/writable/root /root
dropbear
```